# My variable u64 is not saved and appears as undefined

Tags: rust, typescript

When I use the fetch method my variable u64 appears as undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was programming and came across this error. The problem is the following. Note the type of variable to which you have applied the fetch method. Do you have a number? Well that's the problem. Change the number to a letter.